# roscore fails in groovy

Tags: roslaunch, roscore, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte installed and working correctly. I recently installed Groovy and I couldn't run it.

First of all, I source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh from a fresh terminal. Then I run roscore and this is the output:

`$ roscore`

```
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 263, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 206, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, self.port, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 415, in load_config_default
    load_roscore(loader, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 86, in load_roscore
    f_roscore = get_roscore_filename()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 78, in get_roscore_filename
    return os.path.join(r.get_path('roslaunch'), 'resources', 'roscore.xml')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/rospkg/rospack.py", line 149, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: roslaunch
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

If I look for roslaunch: `$ rosversion roslaunch`

```
Cannot locate [roslaunch]
```

and my installed version is ros-groovy-desktop-full, version 1.9.39-0precise-20121230.

Has anyone the same issue? Do you know how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53507/roscore-fails-in-groovy/) by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1471 on 2013-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same question here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/47762/setting-up-ros-groovy-cant-launch-roscore/

Delete /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg* it is outdated.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0